# QLabel text isnt updating when using QTimer

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to get a QLabel to update itself using QTimer, but the text doesn't update when using `.setText()`. If I use `.show()` on `self.price_label` it will re-draw the text on top of the QLabel so that obviously isn't the correct way.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import getters

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("Hello There!")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('logo.png'))
        self.exitMenu = QtWidgets.QAction(" &Exit", self)
        self.exitMenu.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        self.exitMenu.setStatusTip("Leave the app")
        self.exitMenu.triggered.connect(self.close_application)
        self.statusBar()

        self.mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        self.fileMenu = self.mainMenu.addMenu("&File")
        self.fileMenu.addAction(self.exitMenu)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.home)
        self.timer.start(5000)

    def home(self):
        self.quit_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Quit", self)
        self.quit_button.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

        self.quit_button.resize(100,100)
        self.quit_button.move(100, 70)

        self.symbol = getters.pair.get_price().get("symbol")
        self.price = getters.pair.get_price().get("price")

        print(self.symbol)
        print(self.price)

        self.price_label = QtWidgets.QLabel("%s %s" % (self.symbol, self.price), self)
        self.price_label.resize(200, 100)
        self.price_label.move(200, 100)

        self.price_label.setText("%s %s" % (self.symbol, self.price))

        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()

        self.show()


    def close_application(self):
        sys.exit()


def run():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

I'm guessing my QTimer may be incorrectly placed and it's not correctly redrawing the text for QLabel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have this written you are setting up several UI items every five seconds.  Most of what is in your `home` method should be moved to `__init__`.  This way the UI is only set up when the program is started.

If you just want to change the text of the label every five seconds, try this:

```
def __init___(self):
    # previous code here
    self.symbol = getters.pair.get_price().get("symbol")
    self.price = getters.pair.get_price().get("price")

def home(self):
    self.symbol = getters.pair.get_price().get("symbol")
    self.price = getters.pair.get_price().get("price")
    self.price_label.setText('%s %s' % (self.symbol, self.price))
```

Everything that is in your home method that is not in mine, move to `__init__`.  Also be sure to include the first instances of `self.symbol` and `self.price` in `__init__`.

Comment: It works! Thank you for your help. I see how it was better to put UI items in __init__ so they aren't reloaded every five seconds. Why did I need to put the variables in the __init__ method as well as the home method for them to update properly every five seconds?

Comment: You put them in `__init__` first so that when you first set the label up it has the correct symbol and price values.  You reset them in `home` because presumably the values have changed and need to be updated every five seconds when the timer calls `home`.  It's not entirely necessary to define the variables in `__init__` first.  It was just necessary for this example to work correctly with minimal changes.

Comment: Thanks again MalloyDelacroix!